# Grails unique constraint fails on save

Tags: grails

I have the following domain:

```
class Person {
    String name
    static constraints = {
        name maxSize: 25, blank: false, nullable: false, unique: true
    }
}
```

Now on this domain I have added an integration test:

```
class PersonIntegraionTest {
 void testSavePersonUniqueConstraint() {
    def person = //Loading data from xml
    def node = person[1]
    def person1 = ((Person) node.object)

    personService.save(person1)

    assertNotNull "Person id not present", person1.id

    node = person[2]
    def person2 = ((Person) node.object)
    person2.name = person1.name

    personService.save(person2)

    assertTrue "Person2 have errors", person2.hasErrors()
  }
}
```

After running this integration test I am getting the following error:

```
Failure:  |
testSavePersonUniqueConstraint(com.PersonIntegraionTest)
 |
grails.validation.ValidationException: Validation Error(s) occurred during save():
- Field error in object 'com.Person' on field 'name': rejected value [Name2]; codes [com.Person.name.unique.error]
```

Answer (score 0):

On debug mode run this:

```
Person.list()
```

And see what you got so far and what you're trying to save.

See if you already got something which the same as the new one.

Answer (score 0):

You've marked the name as having to be unique so you probably ran the test inserted the name, and now that name is still in the database.  Then you run the test again it fails.  Your database probably isn't being cleaned out before your test runs.  You are not starting from a known state.

As a side note you'll  probably want to check that the name field had the error in the second assert:

```
assertTrue "Non-Unique names are not triggering errors", person2.hasErrors() && person2.errors.fieldErrors.name
```

That way you know you are catching an error on the name field and not some other error.